# Injecting/Acquiring internal modules in PlatypusTS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Using angular, I can retrieve object instances or load modules using the `$injector` like so:

```
export class BaseService {       

        protected $http: angular.IHttpService;
        protected _injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$injector');

        constructor() {
            this.$http = this._injector.get('$http');
        }
        ...
        ...
}
```

I am attempting to do the same thing in the PlatypusTS framework to import the frameworks `plat.Utils` module into a non-registered base class. How can I inject or acquire the `plat.Utils` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I inject or acquire the plat.Utils module

Have the following in your class:

```
protected static _inject: any = {
        _utils: plat.Utils
};

protected _utils: plat.Utils;
```